# Yii2 GridView inline editing

Tags: php, gridview, kendo-ui, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new to `Yii` and would appreciate if someone could advise if there is a way to use GridView with inline editing, i.e. it should be updated with Ajax.
Till now I have:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'title_en',
        'title_mn',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template'=>'{update}{delete}',],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I would like to have something simillar with `Kendo UI Grid` [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline). Please advise which extensions for Yii 2.0 are most popular and easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Popular Extension for Gridview Inline Edit is [Kartik-v Yii2 Editable](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-editable) and **chrisb34/yii2-gridview-editable**.

Few Reference Links and Demos:

1) [Grid Demo](http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo#)
2) [Gridview Editable Example](http://webtips.krajee.com/setup-editable-column-grid-view-manipulate-records/)
3) [How to save Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940418/how-to-save-data-in-model-using-yii2-grid-with-editable-column)
4) [chrisb34 / yii2-gridview-editable](http://hackersome.com/p/chrisb34/yii2-gridview-editable)
5) [chrisb34 / yii2-gridview-editable Demo](http://yii2-demos.chris-backhouse.com/photo)